# geom_density(aes(y=..count..)) plot for multiple groups show a wrong x-axis count

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

1. My data frame (df) consists of 5 columns with 2,000 numerical values for each one.
2. Using reshape I reformatted my data frame to two columns: 1st containing the values (`df$Values`) (a total of 10,000) and a 2nd containing the name of the column (`df$Labels`) from where the value in col 1 is coming from.
3. I will use the 2nd column as a group factor.
4. I generated a `mycolor` and `myshapes` for coloring and setting the shape of lines.
5. With `ggplot` I tried to generate a density plot containing the density plot for the five factors.
   The problem is that the `x-axis` show the counts, which maximum is 10,000. This value does not make any sense because the maximum possible counts for each plot must be 2,000. Anyone knows what is going on? Which is code I need to use to properly correct the x-axis?

`ggplot2`, `geom_density()` plot:

[image: ggplot2 geom_density() plot]

Here is the code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Values, colour=Labels, linetype=Labels))+
geom_density(aes(y=..count..))+
theme_classic()+
scale_colour_manual(values = mycolor)+
scale_linetype_manual(values = myshapes)+
ggtitle("Title")+
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0.5,1.5))
```

Comment: Please can you make your problem reproducible by adding a data, or perhaps better, some random data generating code e.g. `df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(2000, 1, 1), b = rnorm(2000, 2, 1))`

Comment: The maximum of the density is not the same as the maximal number of occurences of some element in your data. If you want to know, how many numbers between a and b are in your data, then you need to integrate the density from a to b. If, say, a = 0.95, b = 1.02 and the density is 10'000 over the entire interval, this would mean that you have 700 element in that interval, which is much less than 10'000.

Comment: You can also dump a small sample of data using `dput(df)`, and putting the result in your post.